# Updating XML node value with SimpleXML API

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have an XML structure:

```
<root>
   <!-- ... -->
   <B ID="444">
        <C></C>  
        <D>Anything</D>
        <E>
            <child1 /*expected outcome came in here*/> /*sometimes here*/ </child1>
            <child2>data2 <!-- instead of here --></child2>
            <child3>data3</child3>
            <child4>data4 /* and also here instead*/ </child4>
        </E>
    </B>
   <!-- ... -->
</root>
```

I made an XPath query to fetch `//*B`, where `child2==data2` and `child4==data4`, like this:

```
$query = "//*[@ID=444]//*['data2' and 'data4']";
$result = $xml->xpath($query);
```

it worked fine. But now, I want to update `data1` and `data3`, after finding a match, using only the simplexml API. Here's what i did, but it's not working correctly:

```
if(!empty($result)){
    $result[0]['data2'] = "Blabla";
    $result[0]['data4'] = "Blaaaaaaaa";
    return $xml->saveXML($File;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how is it better done with simplexml? Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made an XPath query to fetch `//*B`, where `child2==data2` and `child4==data4`, like this:
>
> ```
> $query = "//*[@ID=444]//*['data2' and 'data4']";
> ```

That's wrong already. Where do you think does your attempt compare `child2` with `'data2'` or `child4` with `'data4'`?

Better:

```
$query = "//B[@ID = 444 and .//child2 = 'data2' and .//child4 = 'data4']";
$result = $xml->xpath($query);

foreach ($result as $b) {
    // find first <child2> and <child4> descendants
    $child2 = $b->xpath(".//child2")[0];
    $child4 = $b->xpath(".//child4")[0];

    // set their text values
    $child2[0] = "Blabla";
    $child4[0] = "Blaaaaaaaa";
}

return $xml->saveXML($File);
```

See http://ideone.com/lXtvbP

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak but how about not having knowing what data2 and data4 are in advance, but just want to change or update whatever is in child2 and child4 ?  what expression does that ?

Comment: If you think about that for a few minutes, it will come to you. -- My answer fits your question, you explicitly spoke about *"an XPath query to fetch `//*B`, where `child2==data2` and `child4==data4`"*. If you want something else you should have asked the question differently.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie It's only a matter of removing something from my code. You'll manage, I'm certain.